# ByBit API: is there a way to place Take Profit & Stop Loss orders after a opening a position?

Tags: python, api, trading, cryptocurrency

From the official docs I found this:

```
import bybit
client = bybit.bybit(test=True, api_key="api_key", api_secret="api_secret")
print(client.LinearOrder.LinearOrder_new(
side="Sell",
symbol="BTCUSDT",
order_type="Limit",
qty=0.22,
price=10000,
time_in_force="GoodTillCancel",
reduce_only=False, 
close_on_trigger=False
).result())
```

Additional parameters *take_profit* & *stop_loss* may also be sent. The TP&SL then get placed along with the order.

I'm wondering if there is a way to place TP&SL orders **after** an order is placed. There are no examples in the official docs, and I do not understand any instructions written for those orders in there either.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to attach these orders after entering a position. In the docs they reference set stop, and this is also included in the test.py doc page within the Bybit python install

here is the link to the docs

[Bybit Set Stop](https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/linear/#t-setleverage)

Here is what a stop and TP would look like for a LONG position. Please note that for a long we set what our current pos is for the side argument. (BUY)

```
# Stop Loss
print(client.LinearPositions.LinearPositions_tradingStop(
    symbol="BTCUSDT", 
    side="Buy", 
    stop_loss=41000).result())

# Take profit
print(client.LinearPositions.LinearPositions_tradingStop(
    symbol="BTCUSDT", 
    side="Buy", 
    take_profit=49000).result())
```

Additional note: TP orders are conditional orders, meaning they are sent to the order book once triggered, which results in a market order. If you already know your target level, a limit order may be more suitable. This will go to your active orders, which you will have to cancel. We use a sell argument for this one:

```
# Limit order
print(client.LinearOrder.LinearOrder_new(
    side="Sell",
    symbol="BTCUSDT",
    order_type="Limit",
    qty=0.001,
    price=49000,
    time_in_force="GoodTillCancel",
    reduce_only=True, 
    close_on_trigger=False).result())
```

Cheers my friend and good luck with your coding and trading!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to is to listen to websocket data. What I do is I subscribe to **"execution"** topic. This way, every time your order gets executed you receive an event with all the info about the trade. Then, you can have a callback function that places a trade for you.

Here's the link to the api: https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/inverse/#t-websocketexecution

Here's how to subscribe:

[image]

Here's the sample response:

[image]